# resize UItableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i use this code

```
- (IBAction)gotostatuttableviewcontroller:(id)sender
{ 
    [self.statutsField resignFirstResponder];
    StatusTableViewController *statuttableview =[[StatusTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    statuttableview.Flynumber=statutsField.text;
    [statuttableview.Flynumber retain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statuttableview animated:YES];

 }
```

and this is my interface in interface builder http://hpics.li/19cc67b

But when i build , i have this 
http://hpics.li/188d87e

Why the tableview don't have the same seize that i puted in interface builder ? It's becaus it' a UItableViewcontroller class and not UIViewCotroller ?

@CharlieMezak i do it and now i have this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] loaded the
>   "StatusTableViewController" nib but
>   didn't get a UITableView.'

in this line ( pushviewcontroller)

```
   StatusTableViewController *statuttableview =[[StatusTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatusTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    statuttableview.Flynumber=statutsField.text;
    [statuttableview.Flynumber retain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statuttableview animated:YES];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at your nib file. Check that the File's Owner view outlet is connected to the top level `UIView` and not to the `UITableView`. If it's connected to the table view, then the table view will be treated as the view controller's view. The containing views will be ignored.

Comment: Change your view controller to inherit from UIViewController and not UITableViewController.

Comment: Yes tahnk you now it work :) . If i put UITableViewCotroller , i should put only tableView in my interface ?

Comment: UITableViewController expects its view to be a UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame of the UITableView in viewDidLoad.